# Select a text and highlight it to be permanent and free to draw anything

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with text and I want when I select (mouseover from letter to letter) a particular piece of the text to be highlighted simultaneously with background and underline.

Also I want to draw random stuff in the div with the pointer like in paint.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? At least for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand below example

text text

this part in css

## one

{
color://define color
}

## one:hover

{
color://define highlight color
}

Comment: Maybe canvas is what I want to do. But I don't know how to work with canvas and mouse to draw things. Any tutorial ?